# Lightning Bow Affecting Only Certain People

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know the command:

```
/execute @e[type=Arrow,c=1] ~ ~ ~ summon LightningBolt
```

But I want to know how to make this command only affect certain people. I have a scoreboard objective set up called "bowupgrades" and I want the lightning bow command to only affect those who have "bowupgrades" with a score of 1 (default is 0). How do I do this?

Comment: Can I clarify what you mean by "only affect those who have bowupgrades"? Who has this tag? The people using the bow or those being hit by the arrows?

Comment: @Ben People with bowupgrades at a score of 1 have the lightning bow. those with a bowupgrades score of 0 are stuck with the normal bow.

Answer (score 3):

#### Setup:

Create an objective to keep track of when players fire an arrow:

```
/scoreboard objectives add firedArrow stat.useItem.minecraft.bow
```

#### Repeating commands:

Have the following commands constantly repeating, in this order:

```
/execute @a[score_bowupgrades_min=1,score_firedArrow_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[type=Arrow,c=1,r=3] add Lightning
/scoreboard players set @a[score_firedArrow_min=1] firedArrow 0
/execute @e[type=Arrow,tag=Lightning] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt
```

This makes it so when a player with `bowupgrades >= 1` fires an arrow, they put a "Lightning" tag (1.9+, use objectives for 1.8 or lower) on the arrow, which then makes the arrow constantly summon lightning.

---

## 1.8 compatible

Create an additional objective to keep track of arrows that are lightning, rather than using a tag:

```
/scoreboard objectives add isLightning dummy
```

This version will also need the objective to delay the lightning bolts, as requested in the comments:

```
/scoreboard objectives add lightningTimer dummy
```

Update your repeating commands to the following:

```
/execute @a[score_bowupgrades_min=1,score_firedArrow_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow,c=1,r=3] isLightning 1
/scoreboard players set @a[score_firedArrow_min=1] firedArrow 0
/execute @e[type=Arrow,score_isLightning_min=1,score_lightningTimer_min=20] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Arrow,score_isLightning_min=1] lightningTimer 1
```

Comment: one question(although i know this wuz not in the orignial  question). is their any way to make it so that lightning rapidly strikes the arrow after one second of the player firering? i have realized that with the lighting bow if you do not delay the lighting by one second the lightining damages u as the arrow  flys away.

Comment: if their is no way to do this tell me and i will give u ur rep.

Comment: @gamer103 Create a new dummy objective called `lightningTimer` (`/scoreboard objectives add lightningTimer dummy`), add `/scoreboard players add @e[type=Arrow,tag=Lightning] lightningTimer 1` to the end of your clock, and then change the third command to `/execute @e[type=Arrow,tag=Lightning,score_lightningTimer_min=20] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt`

Comment: it still affects everyone. not just those with a bowupgrade score of 1. PLEASE FIX THIS FAST FOR I NEED THE ANSWER BEFORE TOMMOROW.(June 26,sunday)

Comment: @gamer103 Works fine for me, probably something wrong with your setup. Are you using a very outdated Minecraft version? Are you sure that you've entered all the commands correctly? Are all of the commands being activated, and in the right order? A screenshot could help work out what's wrong.

Comment: i'm doing it right. i'll give u a screen shot in a min or 2

Comment: wait. where do i put the screen shot. edit my question?

Comment: i'm also on minecraft 1.8.9

Comment: can u give me a screen shot of what ur doing?(and possibly quick)

Comment: @gamer103 My current answer uses features only available in 1.9 and above. I'd recommend updating if possible (1.8 was released in 2014), but I'll add a slightly longer 1.8-compatible answer to my post.

Comment: k. i can just switch to 1.9. thanks

Comment: idk whats happening with u but both of ur versions don't work for me.

Comment: @gamer103 I've tested both versions and they should work. Make sure all of the commands are being activated in the correct order, and you have set up the objectives. A screenshot (or world download, if possible) could help work out what's wrong.

Comment: i have done it all in the correct order and i have set up all the objectives. as for a world download i can't do that cuz i have a big custom pvp arena and if i downloaded it i would need to restart. what hapens to me is that only 1 out of like 30 arrows work. idk whats happening but. Can u post a screenshot just in case?

Comment: @gamer103 http://i.imgur.com/6rg2JJe.png - can you post a screenshot of your own, or perhaps a schematic or something of the area with the command blocks?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works in 1.9.* or 1.10 due to the fact of executing an execute command on top of an execute command. Try this command

```
/execute @a[score_bowupgrades_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute [type=Arrow,r=1] ~ ~ ~ summon LightningBolt
```

Comment: it does not work. whenever i try running it i get the fail message of "[16:12:35] Failed to execute 'execute [type=Arrow,r=1] ~ ~ ~ summon LightningBolt' as Grostic403" (Grostic403 is my username).

Comment: can u fix this answer quick cuz i need it very soon or i'm screwed.